# How does Spring trigger a scheduling event with TaskExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

Looking over [the example in the documentation for using the TaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-task-executor-usage), I am a bit confused as to how Spring knows to run the method `public void printMessages()`

```
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;

public class TaskExecutorExample {

    private class MessagePrinterTask implements Runnable {

            private String message;

            public MessagePrinterTask(String message) {
                    this.message = message;
            }

            public void run() {
                    System.out.println(message);
            }

    }

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public TaskExecutorExample(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
            this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    public void printMessages() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                    taskExecutor.execute(new MessagePrinterTask("Message" + i));
            }
    }

}
```

Is the example incomplete or is there some auto-magic going on?

Comment: Hi,If you look at the bean definition in the link you have shared you can see that ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is spring class which in turn creates a ThreadPoolExecutor.In your code you are passing the task(runnable) which needs to be executed.During startup spring scans the beans and create the pool and pass the runnable to a worker thread from the pool.Spring also provides flexibility of running your task as cron or scheduled job.

Comment: This will help you - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch27s04.html AND this too - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html

Comment: So I get that package scanning would see a Runable, but the root question is how does `printMessages()` get called? Inner class `MessagePrinterTask` doesn't make a call to it, there's no annotation around it, nothing special except that it returns void and is public and happens to be in the parent class.  I see that it calls upon `TaskExecutor`... is there some reflection going on?